# Find a solution set for a simple system in rref

Tags: linear-algebra

Given this system:$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

I know that here are 1 equation with 3 unknowns and so we need to invoke 2 parameters to the system and then find out the solution set.

So, I let $y=s$ and $z=t$. From the first row of the rref, I know we can obtain the equation:
$$s+t=1$$

However, I do not know how to proceed because I do not know $x$ should be equal a non-zero constant or I should set it to be zero.

So, my question is: **How to find a basis of Null space of the following system?**

Since I have looked up for textbooks that the pivot position occurs at the leftmost position and I do not know how to deal with this situation. How that you can answer me in an elementary ways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The variables which do not correspond to leading 1's, which in this case are x and z, are the arbitrary parameters.  Using the answer below, the general solution to the system is given by (x,y,z)=(s,1-t,t)=s(1,0,0)+t(0,-1,1)+(0,1,0), as you have; so a basis for the Null space is given by the vectors (1,0,0) and (0,-1,1).

Comment: @user84413 thank you for your comment first but I do not understand your last statement *so a basis for the Null space is given by the vectors (1,0,0) and (0,-1,1)*. may I know why we can omit $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: To find a basis for the Null space of the system, we have to replace the last column by a column of zeros, in which case the solution obtained is the same as before except that now the vector (0,1,0) no longer appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your matrix could just as easily be expressed as $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

That is, the sole pivot (in any case) represents the coefficient of the variable $y$.

You need to let $x = s,\;z = t$, so that $y + z = 1 \implies y = 1-z = 1-t$.

So the general solution is given by $$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} s\\ 1-t\\t\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you your answer. I get this general solution:$$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0 
\\0
\end{pmatrix}
s
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1
\\1
\end{pmatrix}
t+
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1
\\0
\end{pmatrix}$$

May I know we are forced to let $x=s$ in this situation?